# How to solve an image which have transparency after converted from binary in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an image in .png form. It is a circular ball. I have to insert the image into my database by converting it into binary. However, after I retrieved it, it's transparency turned into black color. Does anyone know how can I solve it?

FYI: I know that binary does not recognise transparency.

As requested from Corey: I am using a Windows Form Application to insert the image into database.

```
 private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "image files|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.mp3";
        DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        txtImage.Text = ofd.FileName;
    }
```

And as for the query

```
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Games;Integrated Security=True");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pbImage.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] image = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(image, 0, image.Length);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into CorrespondingBall(blueBallImage) values(@image)", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", image);
```

Comment: A binary field in a database should be able to contain any arbitrary data, including raw PNG files.  Show us your code for storing your PNG into the database.

Comment: Hi @Corey, I have edited it. Do take a look! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The database parts of the code you're using are OK.  I would have written it with `using` blocks, but it's just sample code :)

Binary fields in database tables will store arbitrary collections of bytes, generally with no concern about the format of the data.  Since the database insert code seems to be OK, the problem is earlier than that.

In your code you are converting an image (`pbImage.Image`) to a PNG file.  This seems to be the most likely source of the problem: your source image either doesn't have transparency, or the conversion to PNG is not handling the transparency correctly.

Make sure that your source image has actual transparency.  If you're drawing it in code, make sure you start off by clearing the background to `Color.Transparent` before you start drawing.  Check that you are using a `PixelFormat` that supports an alpha channel.

Try this code:

```
byte[] imgData;
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, 90, 90);
        g.DrawString("Test", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Green, 30, 45);
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        imgData = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

That should create a transparent PNG file in `imgData` which you can save to the database and load back.  Save the file to disk as well, and see what it looks like.

-- Updated...

Since you keep a copy of the filename of the file, you should use that to load the file from disk.  That way you're not losing transparency information or wasting CPU cycles compressing the PNG again.  Use the `ReadAllBytes` method of the `File` class to get the data from disk:

```
byte[] imgFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(txtImage.Text);
```

Then you can write that directly to the database.  That way you have no transformation of the original file at all, it gets loaded straight into the database.  Reading from the database then gives you a byte-for-byte match with the original file.

Comment: Thank you Corey. But I don't understand your codes. pbImage is actually an image that is choosen by browsing it in my computer. It is not draw in code. Sorry for not telling you earlier. I have edited it. Do take a look.

Comment: Corey, I have tried it. However, I got an error in my application. I tried to set the source to a Bitmap Image. However, I go got an unspecified error.